# Problem with creating a window using GLFW (LWJGL)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I'm trying to create a window using GLFW. Window IS created,
but after a few attempts it takes really long before window is created.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zq4IEjcSIJxy5wnXWLrGe46ptHMbKM5R/view?usp=sharing

I can't find any solution for this and don't know what can this be caused by.

Here's a code I am using:

```java
    import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
    import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
    
    import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
    import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             System.out.println("0");
             if(!glfwInit()) {
                 throw  new IllegalStateException("GLFW couldn't be initialized!");
             }
             System.out.println("1");
    
             long window = glfwCreateWindow(450,800,"Test #1",0,0);
    
             if(window == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("GLFW failed to create a window!");
             }
             System.out.println("2");
    
            GLFWVidMode videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    
            glfwSetWindowPos(window,(videoMode.width()-450)/2,(videoMode.height()-800)/2);
    
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
            GL.createCapabilities();
    
            float i = 2;
            float speed = 1;
    
            System.out.println("3");
             while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
                 
                 if(i> 253 || i < 1) 
                     speed *= -1;
                 
                 i+=speed;
                 
                 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
                 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    glColor4f(0.38f,(i%255)/255,(i%255)/255,1.0f);
                     glVertex2f(-0.5f,0.5f);
                     glVertex2f(0.5f,0.5f);
                     glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
                     glVertex2f(-0.5f,-0.5f);
                glEnd();
                 glfwSwapBuffers(window);
                 glfwPollEvents();
    
             }
             System.out.println("4");
             glfwDestroyWindow(window);
             glfwTerminate();
             System.out.println("5");
    
        }
    }
```

Program's output is

```
0
//Now for a really long time nothing
1
2
3
```

So it looks like it takes really long to initialize glfw, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Your code only creates a window once. You can expect some time for `GLFW` to initialize on some platforms.

Comment: I added video showing the problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zq4IEjcSIJxy5wnXWLrGe46ptHMbKM5R/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out, that the problem was related to USB Input Device - in my case - Corsair k55 keyboard.

From some articles and github issues I learend, that that bug is also caused by some other devices (In many cases Corsair, but not only).

The fix is:

- to find out which device causes the bug (by unpluging, that's how I did)
- now (as I found it's my k55) I had to update ICUE (drivers).

Hope it helps ;)